# UglifyJs with webpack just freezes when doing production build

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, uglifyjs

I'm using Webpack, and when I run a production build ie.

```
webpack -p
```

The build never completes.

A quick search says to disable the sourcemap for uglifyjs... but I cannot find a decent explanation on how to do this.

Ideally I would be able to disable the sourceMap from from the configuration.

Finally, this brings up another question which is... shouldn't I want a source map when I create a production build? Disabling the feature seems like a poor workaround.

```
module.exports = {
entry: ["./utils", "./app.js" ],
output: { filename: "bundle.js" },
module:{
 preLoaders:[
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'jshint-loader'
  }
],
loaders: [
  {
    test:/\.es6$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "babel",
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015']
    }
  }
 ]
},
resolve: {
 extensions: ['', '.js', '.es6']
},
watch: true
}
```

UPDATE: Ok... it looks as if the `watch: true` portion of my config was the culprit... but still, it would be good to know how to disable sourceMaps.

Comment: can you post your webpack.config.js?

Comment: Oh man... I think the watch is causing the problem

Comment: watch tells webpack to keep running and automatically build your files as they change. The build finished. The command will keep running till killed.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... thanks.

Comment: Thank for You answer, set watch to false resolved my problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is from @user104317 above, in the comments section.

"Watch" tells webpack to keep running and automatically build your files as they change. The build finished. The command will keep running till killed.